# How to Clear an image control in WPF (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, image, controls

I have an image control with a source image located in my c drive. I get a message that the image is being used by another process whenever I try to delete the original image to change it with another one dynamically. How do I release the image from the image control to be able to delete it.

I tried this variants:

```
string path = ((BitmapImage)img.Source).UriSource.LocalPath;
img.SetValue(System.Windows.Controls.Image.SourceProperty, null);
File.Delete(path);
```

And:

```
string path = ((BitmapImage)img.Source).UriSource.LocalPath;
img.Source = null;
File.Delete(path)
```

But it's not work...

Comment: cross posted? http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/391943/Delete-images-in-WPF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the bitmap image through the stream source property.  That way the app won't put a lock on the file since you loaded it through a stream.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.streamsource(VS.85).aspx

Comment: 2Kevin: Interesting way, but in this situation I need fs.Close() before File.Delete. It's not very convenient. Is there some other option?

Comment: The other option I saw was to copy the image to a temp directory and open the temp file.

Comment: I saw other posts where it looks like the file just locks even after the control should release the image for some reason without explanation.

Answer (score -1):

//this function allows you to load an image from a file and release it

```
 BitmapImage loadPhoto(string path)
    {
        BitmapImage bmi = new BitmapImage();
        bmi.BeginInit();
        bmi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        bmi.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;            
        bmi.UriSource = new Uri(path);
        bmi.EndInit();
        return bmi;
    }
```

Comment: Please add some description about your answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer